# Downloading and drawing images, and they're overdrawing

Tags: java, graphics, download

every "try" I'm download picture and put in *srcImage*, then i make it picture size 75x75(and it works). After that I take void picture(*imageVoid*) 125x75 size, and I want to draw on this void picture my downloaded picture, and then save this file. The first picture goes good, but on the next pictures i can see that new picture writes tight on the old and after several iterations i have something like this:[image]
Thats my part of code:

```
public static void downloadPictures(ArrayList<Channel> channels){
    String url;
    File output;
    BufferedImage imageVoid = null;
    BufferedImage imageNotFound = null;
    BufferedImage newBack;
    BufferedImage srcImage;
    try {
        imageNotFound = ImageIO.read(new File(notImagePass));
        imageVoid = ImageIO.read(new File(voidPass));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("There is no picture for not founded file OR no void picture");
    }
    //==============================
    //==============================Making pictures and checking if link exists
    //==============================
    for (Channel channel : channels) {
        url = channel.getLink();
        if (!channel.ifLinkExists()) {  //=====link exists
            try (InputStream in = URI.create(url).toURL().openStream()) {
                srcImage = ImageIO.read(in);

                Image tmp = srcImage.getScaledInstance(75,75,Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
                BufferedImage dimg = new BufferedImage(75,75,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                Graphics2D g2d = dimg.createGraphics();
                g2d.drawImage(tmp, 0, 0, null);
                g2d.dispose();

                newBack = imageVoid;
                newBack.createGraphics().drawImage(dimg,25,0,null);

                ImageIO.write(newBack, "png", new File(picturesPass + channel.getName() + ".png"));
            } catch (IOException e) {  //=====link exists but source not founded
                output = new File(picturesPass + channel.getName() + ".png");
                try {
                    ImageIO.write(imageNotFound, "png",output);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                }
            }
        } else {  //=====link doesnt exists
            output = new File(picturesPass + channel.getName() + ".png");
            try {
                ImageIO.write(imageNotFound, "png",output);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I checked if I do resize right and it was OK, I checked my void picture,maybe there's something I don't know about downloading, maybe its somewhere in the buffer(??), maybe it's because od method drawImage, idk.

Comment: `newBack = imageVoid;` - you are always painting on top of the same image. You can't just assign the original image using the equals statement. You need to paint the imageVoid onto the newBack BuffererredImage the same way you paint the dimg.

Comment: Thank you, i didn't know about useless of equals statement in this case! I made even more, used BufferedImage.BITMASK to make every time new transparrent picture 125x75px, and then draw my srcImage on it, so thats code in try:
`srcImage = ImageIO.read(in).getScaledInstance(75,75,Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
                    newBack = new BufferedImage(125, 75, BufferedImage.BITMASK);
                    newBack.createGraphics().drawImage(srcImage,25,0,null);
                    ImageIO.write(newBack, "png", new File(picturesPass + channel.getName() + ".png"));`